# How can I get the value of an attribute from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkbox which is responsible for showing/hiding a div. I created a custom attribute 'myDiv' and put the name of the div which the checkbox is responsible for there.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" myDiv="divRegisteration" myText=" הרשמה - " runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Font-Size="18px" Font-Bold="true" Text=" הרשמה - הצג" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"/>
```

When I try to get the name of the div from the code behind, I get an error:

```
 protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)(sender)).Checked==true)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)(sender);            
            object div = chk.Parent.FindControl(chk.Attributes["myDiv"]);
```

it does not find the attribute "myDiv". for some reason it only finds 2 attributes which I dont even know where they came from. Is there another way to get a custom attribute?

Comment: Have you checked the Parent.Controls property for the presence of the divRegistration?

Comment: why dont you just say CheckBox1.Attributes["myDiv"]

Comment: CheckBox1 is not a child of divRegisteration, that is the problem..

Comment: i wouldn't say CheckBox1.Attributes["myDiv"], becuase i have 4 checkboxes and 4 divs, and i want this to work for all of them. I don't want to create a CheckBox_CheckChanged for each and every one of them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316516/textbox-custom-attribute-is-empty

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't c# find the attribute? asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693608/why-doesnt-c-sharp-find-the-attribute-asp-net)

Answer (score 2):

You can only set attributes to render at client side, it is not possible to directly access the attribute value (at server side) when from is `POSTED`. To access the attribute value, you can use hidden field which can be set at client side through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using jquery

```
if ($('#CheckBox1').is(':checked')) {

    $("#Urdiv").show();
} else {
    $("#Urdiv").hide();
}
```

use clientId at CheckBox1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the value of an attribute from code behind.
For example, 
if you have a checkbox control like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="chkBoxCreate" class="item" itemid="1" onclick="Create();" />
```

then you can get it's value in code behind like below:

```
string itemId = chkBoxCreate.Attributes["itemid"];
```

Enjoy :)